Divide goods income to backlogs using optaplanner
I'm totally new to optapanner and as we use quarkus I hope I can solve a problem with it.
My problem is as follows: In an ERP System we have backlogs (sales order positions not yet deliverable cause no goods in warehouse)
On the purchase side we have an order with positions and if that order arrives at the warehouse I want optaplanner to solve which sales backlogs should be reserved.
So in general we have the following domain model:

So what I want optaplanner to solve is which sales order positions can / should be delivered with which income amount. Of cause we have some hard and soft constraints here:
hard: if the income has a backlogId that goods has been ordered for a particular sales order and must be used for it
soft:

the more sales orders are deliverable in hole the better
If the goods have a batch at goods receipt, the goods with the earliest expiry date should be reserved first.
...

As we may have the situation where multiple sales order positions can get deliverable by one income position and also that one sales order positions need multiple income positions we have a n:m relationship between Backlog and Income?!
As I read in the design guide I should create a relationship entity to solve the n:m relationship: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#domainModelingGuide:

For example, in the Employee Rostering starter application the ShiftAssignment class is the many-to-many relationship between Shift and Employee

But when I have a look at the source code I cannot find the TaskAssignment Class. (maybe the docs are outdated?)
So can anybody point me in the right direction if and how my problem would be solvable with optaplanner?
I do not expect anyone to write me the code - just some infos what should be my PlanningEntity and what my PlanningVariables, because I think that is my biggest understanding problem at the moment.
